# Spring Boot returns 404

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

I would like to get a running Springboot Application with Java Backend.

I tried an example application of the web.
I runs on Tomcat. I can install the maven, and run the jar.
I can open the Localhost:8082/ and it returns some .json document.

What i cannot do is to jump to some .html page.
Is there an error in my structure?

Strucure:

[image]

HomeController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
   public String home() {
       return "index";
   }
   @RequestMapping("/test")
   public String test() {
       return "test";
   }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .html
server.port=8082
```

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootDemoApplication  {
   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(BootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
  }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Run-Output:

[image]

The mapping should work:

```
2020-12-03 10:09:23.444  INFO 4764 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/test]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.HomeController.test()
2020-12-03 10:09:23.446  INFO 4764 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/home]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.controller.HomeController.home()
```

I have tried to change the application.properties into:

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix = resources/static/views/
```

and

```
 spring.mvc.view.prefix = /static/views/
```

this had no effect on the result.

Is there an error, i cannot see?

Thanks

MY POM.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>bootdemo</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>bootDemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add @ComponentScan to the main class`@SpringBootApplication @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HomeController.class) public class BootDemoApplication  {`

Comment: Adding @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = HomeController.class) lead to:  
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project bootdemo: There are test failures.

Comment: Which version of spring boot you use ? for me 2.4.0

Comment: I added pom.xml above

Comment: i can't see any error on yor pom.xml , but you can change the version of your spring-boot-starter-web from 1.5.3.RELEASE to 2.4.0 and try

Comment: Done, but it isn´t compiling with @ComponentScan

Comment: You Can remove it and recompile

Answer (score 0):

fix application properties.

```
spring:
    mvc:
       view:
        suffix : .html
```

and call url : http://localhost:8082/views/index

Comment: I do not use thymeleaf.

Comment: Changed it to spring.mvc.view.prefix = static/views/ but it is not working

Answer (score -1):

You can use thymeleaf as template engine and put your views under the templates folder
src/main/resources > templates,
thanks

Comment: I think that will not solve my problem in having a minimal running sample. Can you see an error in structure?

Comment: try to review your entire code , or try to run a new simple project

Comment: Yeah, i tried it this is the second one. Is there an error in Maaping you think?

Comment: I think other Controllers are not affected at this point!

Comment: try to remove   @Autowired
   UserRepository userRepository; from your main class and check it please